# Excel hyperlinks to external Excel files behave differently depending on the way they were created (formula or manual edit)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, hyperlink

I want to create a central Excel file with lots of hyperlinks pointing to individual external Excel files located in a sub-folder; this central Excel file will be used as a kind of table of contents.

Before that I created a self-contained central Excel file with hyperlinks pointing to various tabs within the same Excel file but it got too large and wasn't practicable to work with. That's why I want to move these tabs to individual external Excel files with a 'master' central Excel file.

When clicking on an hyperlink within the central Excel file, I want the Excel file where the link points to to automatically open and the cursor to be on a defined tab and on a defined cell (exactly like internal hyperlinks within a given Excel file).

The issue is: When creating this hyperlink with a formula (what I want to do), the underlying Excel file doesn't open, nothing happens (there is no error), unless the underlying Excel file is already opened.

But: When creating this hyperlink manually with right click etc. and without formula (this is not what I want to do), the underlying Excel file opens (but the location of the cursor cannot be defined).

Some explanations: The central Excel file is located somewhere and has 2 cells whose contents are described below. The individual external Excel file is located in a subfolder (w.r.t. the folder where the central Excel file is located) called 'Output2' and is called 'Worksheet local relative path.xlsx': The value '456' is in cell A1.

1. Hyperlink with a formula:
   `= HYPERLINK("[Output2\Worksheet local relative path.xlsx]" & "'Feuil1'" & "!" & "$A$10"; INDIRECT("'" & LEFT(CELL("filename";A1);FIND("[";CELL("filename";A1))-1) & "Output2\[Worksheet local relative path.xlsx]" & "Feuil1" & "'!" & "$A$1"))`.
2. Hyperlink 'by hand': Right click, 'Hyperlink...', 'Existing File or Web Page', 'Address:', I browse in the subfolder 'Output2' and choose the individual external Excel file 'Worksheet local relative path.xlsx'.

Do you know a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: it consists in adding one intermediate step and storing the second argument of the function `HYPERLINK` in another cell, say B1.

B1 now contains `= INDIRECT("'" & LEFT(CELL("filename";A1);FIND("[";CELL("filename";A1))-1) & "Output2\[Worksheet local relative path.xlsx]" & "Feuil1" & "'!" & "$A$1")`.

And the other original formula now becomes: `= HYPERLINK("[Output2\Worksheet local relative path.xlsx]" & "'Feuil1'" & "!" & "$A$10"; B1)`.

Now when clicking on the generated link, the Excel file opens.